# Matlab script to display port number with signal name

Tags: matlab, simulink

I am trying to find out all the output port in simulink model 
**LaneA_ICD_Fccroot** is the model name

I am using the below script which lets me find all output port name

```
simBlockH = get_param('LaneA_ICD_Fccroot', 'Handle');
handles = find_system(simBlockH, 'LookUnderMasks', 'on', 'FollowLinks', 'on', 'SearchDepth', 1, 'BlockType', 'Inport');
portNames = cellstr(get_param(handles, 'Name'))
```

Output
portNames =

```
  144×1 cell array

    {'g_ECU_1_1_1_Activation'    }
    {'g_ECU_1_1_2_Activation'    }
    {'g_ECU_1_1_3_Activation'    }
    {'g_SCU_1_1_Activation'      }
    {'g_SRV_1_1_Activation'      }
```

What changes should I do to also get the port number.

something like this

```
144×1 cell array

    {'g_ECU_1_1_1_Activation'  1  }
    {'g_ECU_1_1_2_Activation'  2   }
    {'g_ECU_1_1_3_Activation'  3  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a way after trying for an hour

```
simBlockH = get_param('LaneA_ICD_Fccroot', 'Handle')
handles = find_system(simBlockH, 'LookUnderMasks', 'on', 'FollowLinks', 'on', 'SearchDepth', 1, 'BlockType', 'Inport');
portInfo = [get_param(handles, 'Name'), get_param(handles, 'Port')]
```

This gives both info

```
portInfo = [get_param(handles, 'Name'), get_param(handles, 'Port')]
```